# Display values from php while loop to dropdown in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

When a hyperlink 'Add More' is clicked, a dropdown list is added using jquery. I want the values in this dropdown to be generated from the mysql database using php.
I tried many ways,but i not able to get the values from php to jquery.. The values retrieved from mysql database using while loop should be displayed in the dropdown using jquery. Thanks

The values in $val should be displayed in dropdown options
Here is the sample

php code retrieving values from database

```
<?php
 $aquery = "SELECT * from filter";
  $aresult =$base->execute_query($aquery);
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($aresult))
                {
               $val=$row[1];
               }
?>
```

jquery where $val values should be added in dropdown

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.my-form .add-box').click(function(){

        var box_html = $('<select><option><?php echo $val; ?></option>');


        $('.add-box:last').before(box_html);

        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Please help me.Thanks

Comment: You want to add option on click event, not on page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this on button click as your code then try this solution:

```
var box_html = '<select><?php foreach ($val as $value) {
    echo "<option>$value</option>"  ;
}?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

The PHP Script is actually over-writing on your $val.

Perhaps you can do the following:

```
<?php
  $val = "";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($aresult)) {
    $val .= "<option value=". $row[1] .">". $row[1] ."</option>";
  }
?>
```

and your JavaScript code should suffice in this case, just remove the option tags before the php script.
Hope this helps.

```
var box_html = $('<select><?php echo $val; ?></select>');
```

Answer (score 0):

php will build you an array

you need to convert it to java object  json_encode

try var abc=

also when your printing it you need to run a loop through the object  after creating the select section

see each()   jquery